# Finding the squares of each number in a user input list. (Python 3.x)

Tags: python, math, user-input

I'm currently working on an assignment for a course where I have to accept a list of numbers from a user, and then take that list, find the sum of the numbers combined (no issues there), and finally find the squares of each individual value in that list. I am having trouble with developing the function I'm calling "squareEach". I have tried a few ideas but it has ended up printing "*none*" in my print line when calling the function or an error. I feel I may be missing something and if someone could point me in the right direction for how to develop a function to square each value in an input list, I'd really appreciate it!

If I need to clear a bit more up about my problem I'll do so. A sample of the code and what/where I want to put code is below. This is my first post so I'm sorry if the layout is a bit sloppy.

```
#function "squareEach" here



def sumList(nums):
    total=0
    for n in nums:
        total=total+n
    return total

def main():
    print("This program finds the sum of a list of numbers and finds the")
    print("square of each number in the list.\n")
    nums=map(int,input("Enter the numbers separated by a space: ").split())

    print("The sum is", sumList(nums))

    #Line that prints what the squares are for each value e.g("The squares 
   for each value are... ")


main()
```

Comment: I don't see where you attempted to square the values. If you could share that part, it would be much easier to spot the problem.

Comment: Most likely you're just missing a correct `return` statement in the function. But we can't tell if you don't show your function. We don't need to see the working `sumList()` function, that's irrelevant to the question.

Comment: What are the exact conditions for your training course? :-) Because the value sum already exists in Python as the built-in function `sum()`. For example `sum([2,5,8])` gives the result as integer `10`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you use the `<map>` object type. The `nums` variable is the object type `class <map>`. Unfortunately, the contents of the object/class will change in its use, in your first function, in the cycle `for`. Then, the user must re-enter a new numbers into the `nums` variable. The function for calculating the square root is simple, even without using the `math` module and that is:
`n**(1/2.0)`

```
def squareEach(numbers):
    result = {}
    for n in numbers:
        result[n] = n ** (1 / 2.0)
    return result
    # result is dictionary data type, but you can change the function, if you need another data type as the result

def sumList(numbers):
    total = 0
    for n in numbers:
        total += n
    return total


nums = list(map(int, input("Enter the numbers separated by space: ").split()))
# nums variable is the <list> type variable with a <int> entries

print("The sum is", sumList(nums))
print("The suqare for each is", squareEach(nums))
```

Comment: you've just calculated the square root. OP asked for square (n**2)

Comment: Oh, sorry, my fault. So let the user change himself, according to his own needs :-). So, instead of `result[n] = n ** (1 / 2.0)` will be used `result[n] = n ** 2` (in the case of the use of the result in the dictionary data type).